# Vpn on demand in ios 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, vpn

I want to use `VPN on Demand` feature that is available in `Network Extension framework`,I want to connect the VPN when the specific URL or site is open in the browser.

For Example: when I write `www.google.com` my VPN will be connected and not on any other sites.

After a lot of searching on internet,I tried the following code

```
NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
 [manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"Load error: %@", error);
            } else {


NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 alloc] init];
   p.username = @"Username";
   p.passwordReference = [res objectForKey:@"v_PersistentRef"];
   p.serverAddress = strAddress;
   p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodCertificate;
   p.serverCertificateIssuerCommonName = @"COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA";
   p.serverCertificateCommonName =strAddress;
   p.identityData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"point-to-client2" ofType:@"p12"]];
   p.identityDataPassword = @"vpnuser";
   p.localIdentifier = strAddress;
   p.remoteIdentifier = strAddress;
   p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;
   p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
   [manager setProtocol:p];

   NSLog(@"password: %@", [manager protocol].passwordReference);
   [manager setOnDemandEnabled:YES];
   [manager setEnabled:YES];
```

Then setting the onDemandRules by the following code:

```
 NEEvaluateConnectionRule * ru = [[NEEvaluateConnectionRule alloc] initWithMatchDomains:@[@"google.com"]  andAction:NEEvaluateConnectionRuleActionConnectIfNeeded];


ru.probeURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];


NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ru, nil];
 NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection *ec =[[NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection alloc] init];
ec.interfaceTypeMatch = 2;
[ec setConnectionRules:arr];
 NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ec, nil];
            NSLog(@"onDemandRules: %@", arr2);
//
            [manager setOnDemandRules:arr2];
            [manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN Profile"];
            [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                if(error) {
                    NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
                }
                else {
                 NSLog(@"Saved");
                }
```

Here the VPN configuration profile is updated and then start VPN connection through the following code:

```
NSError *startError;
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];
    if(startError) {
        NSLog(@"Start error: %@", startError.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection established!");
    }
```

Now I faced the following problems:

1)When the profile is updated the ondemand feature is not working as when I write in the browser Url i.e www.google.com,the vpn is not connected.So I cannot understand what I did wrong in the code ?

2)How to give the dynamic domain or url like what I placed in the `initWithMatchDomains:@[@"google.com"]` or in the `probeUrl` that will be workable for google.com as well as google.de or any google domain??

I know its quite a long and detailed question but I really want help.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, check out my answer, maybe it will work in your case
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577976/1758481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,I am going to answer my question as I almost solve the problem.
The `On demand Vpn` feature is perfectly working as I did a slightly modified the code as follows:

I just made an array for the domain

```
NSArray *arrDomains =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"youtube.com","google.com",nil];
```

Then  Evaluate the connection rule

```
 NEEvaluateConnectionRule * ru = [[NEEvaluateConnectionRule alloc] initWithMatchDomains:arrDomains  andAction:NEEvaluateConnectionRuleActionConnectIfNeeded];
```

Then using the property

```
ru.useDNSServers = arrDomains;
```

Then the remaining code is same as above mentioned in the question.

```
NSArray *arrRules = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ru,nil];
                            NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection *ec = [[NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection alloc] init];
                            ec.interfaceTypeMatch = 2;
                            [ec setConnectionRules:arrRules];
                            NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ec, nil];
                            NSLog(@"onDemandRules: %@", arr2);
                            [manager setOnDemandRules:arr2];
```

The above code can create vpn connection on the domains defined in the array,this is the answer to my first question.

And to answer my second question what I have searched on the internet that to make the dynamic domain use wildcard `*` but it will be only used only as the left label of the domain name `e.g. *.example.com.`,no other positions the `*` will work.

I hope this will help others who also faced the same problem.